# Weird behavior by db.cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sqlite, ipython

So I was trying learn sqlite and how to use it from Ipython notebook, and I have a sqlite object named db.

I am executing this command:

> sel=" " " SELECT * FROM candidates;" " "
>
> c=db.cursor().execute(sel)

and when I do this in the next cell:

> c.fetchall()

it does print out all the rows but when I run this same command again i.e. I run
`c.fetchall()` again it doesn't print out anything, it just displays a two square brackets with nothing inside them. But when I run the above first command ie, `c=db.cursor().execute(sel)` and then run `db.fetchall()` it again prints out the table.

This is very weird and I don't understand it, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `.fetchall()` makes your cursor(c) pointing the last row.
if you want to select your DB again, you should .execute again.

Or, if you just want to use your fetched data again, you can store `c.fetchall()` into your variable.

Answer (score 0):

It return empty list because cursor points the last row of the table.

```
sel=" " " SELECT * FROM candidates;" " "
c=db.cursor().execute(sel)

c.fetchall()
```

As given in document(This routine fetches all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning a list. An empty list is returned when no rows are available.)